# Making Google Drive API requests using Okta authentication

Tags: authentication, google-drive-api, okta

I'm looking for the best practice to make requests as a third-party app to Google Drive's APIs that are authenticated with Okta.

**Assumptions:**

1. Google's services are being authenticated using Okta (User go to drive.google.com >> redirect to Okta >> authentication >> Google Drive is available).
2. We have a public app on Google - all works easily for non-Okta users.

What will be the best practice solution? Creating an Okta app? Exchanging access tokens in runtime? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the main role of Okta in Google Workspace, I found that OAuth 2.0 works as same as it works if Google authenticates the user.

You should trigger a simple authentication with Google, which by the end of the process, you'll receive an access token you can use.

Actually, Google uses SMAL to authenticate the user and then show a consent screen for additional scopes.

[Graphic flow in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeGJ4.png)

Comment: do you have pointer to any documentation? I can only find documentation on how to use Google API Gateway as a Okta user, but no information about Google APIs (such as Google Drive).

In my case users are already logged in using their Okta account, and I need to access Google Drive associated to their Okta account.

Comment: You can follow [Google's OAuth2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) -- Okta pushes the users over Google's login screen (where they insert user and pass) but not over the consent screen (where they grant the requested scopes).

Comment: @yalovich Hi, I'm struggling with this issue right now. I am using `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse()` to get the access token. Is this not the "simple authentication" to which you are referring?

Comment: @MicheleVolpato were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @Imonniger not really. I changed flow of the app. Instead of logging the user in first and then ask for permission to use Google Drive, I ask directly for Google Drive permissions, which will ask the user to login in a Google account. They will use their Okta linked email address, which makes the web view open the Okta login screen and so on.

Comment: @MicheleVolpato Interesting, I feel like that's what I'm doing. I am getting the Okta popup before the Google popup. But, everything after still fails for me.

Comment: @Imonninger That happens often to me when using Google APIs. Check if your account is among the test accounts list and the OAuth consent screen is in testing mode. I wish you good luck, fellow engineer.

Comment: @MicheleVolpato Thanks! Yeah, it is and it is. I've tried internal too. But, no dice.